# Java Prettify on Android

Tags: java, android

How can i use Java Prettify on Android?
I'm making a text editor for web-development.
I need to syntax highlight the codes of HTML, CSS and JavaScript
I've seen several post here that they have used Java Prettify successfully, but I can't seem to figure out how they did that from scratch.

I've seen a post where it instructs people to just copy the jar of Java Prettify into the Android project, but it seems that I can't find the jar of Java Prettify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it this?  https://github.com/ccrama/java-prettify/releases